# Creating a nested array with looping in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, loops, multidimensional-array

I have 2 MySQL tables, where I extract data with following SQL statements:

Categories: `SELECT cat_id, cat_name FROM categories`

Products: `SELECT pro_id, pro_name, pro_category FROM products`

Of course, `pro_category` is foreign key for `cat_id`

I'd like to reach the following JSON data:

```
"categories":[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Guitars",
        "products":[
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Fender Statocaster"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Gibson Les Paul"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Basses",
        "products":[
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Fender Jazz Bass"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "MusicMan StingRay"
            }
        ]
    }   
]
```

So I have to do an array of categories and, for each element, a sub-array of products (then I'll go with `json_encode()`).

Looping through categories and create the first array is quite easy, but I'm totally stuck on how to create the products sub-array... Here's my code, and the question marks are the point where I stopped because I don't know what to do:

```
$categories = array();
while ($row_rsCategories = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsCategories)) { 
    $categories[] = array(
        'id' => $row_rsCategories['cat_id'],
        'name' => $row_rsCategories['cat_name'],
        'products' => array(
            ???????
        ),
    );
}
```

Please, can you help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$categories = array();
while ($row_rsCategories = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsCategories)) { 

    $product_array = array();
    $product_array_query = mysql_query("SELECT pro_id, pro_name, pro_category FROM products WHERE pro_category = '".$row_rsCategories['cat_id']."'");

    while($product_array_fetch = mysql_fetch_array($product_array_query)) {

       $product_array[] = array("id"=>$product_array_fetch['pro_id'],"name"=>$product_array_fetch['pro_name']);

    }                

    $categories[] = array(
        'id' => $row_rsCategories['cat_id'],
        'name' => $row_rsCategories['cat_name'],
        'products' => $product_array,
    );
}
```

Comment: Thnaks, this works!!! Do the products query, called so many times, can affect performance?

Comment: @Ivan: I think you will have to use a inner for loop. please consider using `PHP PDO` or `mysqli extentions` instead of the default `mysql_*` functions as they are no longer recommended by php community and are vulnerable to security threats like `mysql injection`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$categories = array();
while ($row_rsCategories = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsCategories)) { 
    $categories[$row_rsCategories['cat_id']] = array(
        'id' => $row_rsCategories['cat_id'],
        'name' => $row_rsCategories['cat_name'],
        'products' => array(),
    );
}

while ($row_rsProducts = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsProducts)) {
    $categories[$row_rsProducts['pro_category']]['products'][] = array(
         'id' => $row_rsProducts['pro_id'],
         'name' => $row_rsProducts['pro_name'],
    );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I use a `JOIN` query to order product by its category id, so that products belongs to an category will come together. Traverse through the result array and create new category if you see the `cat_id` change.

```php
$db = new PDO($connectionString);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM products t1 LEFT JOIN categories t2 ON t1.pro_category = t2.cat_id ORDER BY t2.cat_id";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
if($stmt->execute())
{
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $currentCategory = NULL;
    $categories = array();
    foreach($rows as $r)
    {
        if ($currentCategory == NULL || $r['cat_id' != $currentCategory['id'])
        {
            $currentCategory = array(
                'id' => $r['cat_id'],
                'name' => $r['cat_name'],
                'products' => array();
            );
            $categories[] = $currentCategory;
        }
        $currentCategory['products'][] = array(
            'id' => 'pro_id',
            'name' => 'pro_name',
        )
    }
}
else
{
    var_dump($stmt->errorInfo());
}
```